# List of all possible unions of given sets

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to generate a list of all possible unions of some sets to generate a topological space from a given basic sets.
For ex: Given

```
{1}, {2}, {4}, {1,3}
```

I should get

`{{}, {1}, {2}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`

I found the following interesting post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814059/generating-topological-space-diagram-in-mathematica/8815337

But it includes intersection of sets as well.

Comment: Try the `topoCover` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815337) in the post you've linked, For example: `topoCover[{{1}, {2}, {4}, {1,3}}]` returns `{{}, {1}, {2}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sets = {{1}, {2}, {4}, {1, 3}};

Union[Union @@@ Subsets[sets]]
(*    {{}, {1}, {2}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4},
       {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}        *)
```